# Programming ATUC256L4U using only Arduino ISP

Tags: avr

I heard that you can program any AVR Microcontroller by just using Arduino ISP Can I program ATUC256L4U by just hooking it up to Arduino ISP and Caps, Crystals and etc. Or do I need to do some more work like you know the fuses and all ?

Comment: You can set the fuses through your ISP programmer.

Comment: Only the fuses or anything more.